# Is the auto-correlation of a frame transient based on the physical characteristics of a device?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, packet-analysis, hardware, frame-relay

I am currently studying ways to fingerprint Wi-Fi devices based on their physical characteristics and I was struck by a question after reading Section B of this paper
http://www.ccs-labs.org/bib/bloessl2013ofdm-tr/bloessl2013ofdm-tr.pdf

I wondered whether the auto-correlation of a frame transient over time is based on the physical characteristics of Wi-Fi devices (e.g., hardware imperfections). Also, I wondered whether the auto-correlation of a frame transient over time could eventually be used for fingerprinting a Wi-Fi device.

I looked into the current literature, but found no attempts at fingerprinting Wi-Fi devices with the auto-correlation of a frame transient.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

More INFO: I believe that theoretically this would be possible. But in practice would the auto-correlation of devices with the same or different chipset be be sufficiently different from each other to be able to identify and fingerprint them?

Comment: Please edit and extend your question and don't put comments in "answers".